# Profile Pic not displaying on Card View in Andorid Studio Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-storage

I am trying to get a users profile pic to be displayed beside their booking on a card in my recyclerview. The profile pic is displaying in my nav drawer, a default one for non-google users, or the profile pic of the Google user. However imageUri appears empty when I call it and the images are not being stored in my firebase storage bucket. I have linked my firebase and implemented the relevant SDK.

Here is my model.

```
@Parcelize
data class BookModel(
//    var id : Long = 0,
    var uid: String? = "",
    var name: String = "N/A",
    var phoneNumber: String = "N/A",
    var email: String? = "N/A",
    var date: String = "",
    var bike: Int = 0,
    var profilepic: String = "",
    /*var lat: Double = 0.0,
    var longitude: Double = 0.0,
    var zoom: Float = 0f,*/
    var pickup: String = "",
    var dropoff: String = "",
    var price: Double = 20.0,
    /*var amount: Int = 0*/
) : Parcelable
{
    @Exclude
    fun toMap(): Map<String, Any?> {
        return mapOf(
//            "id" to id,
            "uid" to uid,
            "name" to name,
            "phoneNumber" to phoneNumber,
            "email" to email,
            "date" to date,
            "bike" to bike,
            "profilepic" to profilepic,
            "pickup" to pickup,
            "dropoff" to dropoff,
            "price" to price
        )
    }
}

@Parcelize
data class Location(
    var lat: Double = 0.0,
    var longitude: Double = 0.0,
    var zoom: Float = 0f,
    var depot: String = "Waterford"
) : Parcelable
```

Here is my FirebaseImageManager

```
package com.wit.mad2bikeshop.firebase

import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
import android.net.Uri
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask
import com.squareup.picasso.MemoryPolicy
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import com.wit.mad2bikeshop.utils.customTransformation
import timber.log.Timber
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import com.squareup.picasso.Target

object FirebaseImageManager {
    var storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference
    var imageUri = MutableLiveData<Uri>()

    fun checkStorageForExistingProfilePic(userid: String) {
        val imageRef = storage.child("photos").child("${userid}.jpg")
        val defaultImageRef = storage.child("ic_book_nav_header.png")

        imageRef.metadata.addOnSuccessListener { //File Exists
            imageRef.downloadUrl.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                imageUri.value = task.result!!
            }
            //File Doesn't Exist
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            imageUri.value = Uri.EMPTY
        }
    }

    fun uploadImageToFirebase(userid: String, bitmap: Bitmap, updating : Boolean) {
        // Get the data from an ImageView as bytes
        val imageRef = storage.child("photos").child("${userid}.jpg")
        //val bitmap = (imageView as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
        val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        lateinit var uploadTask: UploadTask

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos)
        val data = baos.toByteArray()

        imageRef.metadata.addOnSuccessListener { //File Exists
            if(updating) // Update existing Image
            {
                uploadTask = imageRef.putBytes(data)
                uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener { ut ->
                    ut.metadata!!.reference!!.downloadUrl.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                        imageUri.value = task.result!!
                    }
                }
            }
        }.addOnFailureListener { //File Doesn't Exist
            uploadTask = imageRef.putBytes(data)
            uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener { ut ->
                ut.metadata!!.reference!!.downloadUrl.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    imageUri.value = task.result!!
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun updateUserImage(userid: String, imageUri : Uri?, imageView: ImageView, updating : Boolean) {
        Picasso.get().load(imageUri)
            .resize(200, 200)
            .transform(customTransformation())
            .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(object : Target {
                override fun onBitmapLoaded(bitmap: Bitmap?,
                                            from: Picasso.LoadedFrom?
                ) {
                    Timber.i("DX onBitmapLoaded $bitmap")
                    uploadImageToFirebase(userid, bitmap!!,updating)
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                }

                override fun onBitmapFailed(e: java.lang.Exception?,
                                            errorDrawable: Drawable?) {
                    Timber.i("DX onBitmapFailed $e")
                }

                override fun onPrepareLoad(placeHolderDrawable: Drawable?) {}
            })
    }

    fun updateDefaultImage(userid: String, resource: Int, imageView: ImageView) {
        Picasso.get().load(resource)
            .into(object : Target {
                override fun onBitmapLoaded(bitmap: Bitmap?,
                                            from: Picasso.LoadedFrom?
                ) {
                    Timber.i("DX onBitmapLoaded $bitmap")
                    uploadImageToFirebase(userid, bitmap!!,false)
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                }

                override fun onBitmapFailed(e: java.lang.Exception?,
                                            errorDrawable: Drawable?) {
                    Timber.i("DX onBitmapFailed $e")
                }

                override fun onPrepareLoad(placeHolderDrawable: Drawable?) {}
            })
    }
}
```

My FirebaseAuthManager...

```
package com.wit.mad2bikeshop.firebase

import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider
import com.wit.mad2bikeshop.R
import timber.log.Timber

class FirebaseAuthManager(application: Application) {

    private var application: Application? = null

    var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null
    var liveFirebaseUser = MutableLiveData<FirebaseUser>()
    var loggedOut = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    var errorStatus = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    var googleSignInClient = MutableLiveData<GoogleSignInClient>()

    init {
        this.application = application
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        if (firebaseAuth!!.currentUser != null) {
            liveFirebaseUser.postValue(firebaseAuth!!.currentUser)
            loggedOut.postValue(false)
            errorStatus.postValue(false)
            FirebaseImageManager.checkStorageForExistingProfilePic(
                firebaseAuth!!.currentUser!!.uid)
        }
        configureGoogleSignIn()
    }

    fun login(email: String?, password: String?) {
        firebaseAuth!!.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email!!, password!!)
            .addOnCompleteListener(application!!.mainExecutor, { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    liveFirebaseUser.postValue(firebaseAuth!!.currentUser)
                    errorStatus.postValue(false)
                } else {
                    Timber.i("Login Failure: $task.exception!!.message")
                    errorStatus.postValue(true)
                }
            })
    }

    fun register(email: String?, password: String?) {
        firebaseAuth!!.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email!!, password!!)
            .addOnCompleteListener(application!!.mainExecutor, { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    liveFirebaseUser.postValue(firebaseAuth!!.currentUser)
                    errorStatus.postValue(false)
                } else {
                    Timber.i("Registration Failure: $task.exception!!.message")
                    errorStatus.postValue(true)
                }
            })
    }
    fun logOut() {
        firebaseAuth!!.signOut()
        Timber.i( "firebaseAuth Signed out")
        googleSignInClient.value!!.signOut()
        Timber.i( "googleSignInClient Signed out")
        loggedOut.postValue(true)
        errorStatus.postValue(false)
    }

    private fun configureGoogleSignIn() {

        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(application!!.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()

        googleSignInClient.value = GoogleSignIn.getClient(application!!.applicationContext,gso)
    }

    fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(acct: GoogleSignInAccount) {
        Timber.i( "DonationX firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.id!!)

        val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.idToken, null)
        firebaseAuth!!.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(application!!.mainExecutor) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success, update with the signed-in user's information
                    Timber.i( "signInWithCredential:success")
                    liveFirebaseUser.postValue(firebaseAuth!!.currentUser)

                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Timber.i( "signInWithCredential:failure $task.exception")
                    errorStatus.postValue(true)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

My Home activity

```
package com.wit.mad2bikeshop.ui.home

import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import androidx.navigation.ui.*
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import com.wit.mad2bikeshop.R
import com.wit.mad2bikeshop.databinding.HomeBinding
import com.wit.mad2bikeshop.databinding.NavHeaderBinding
import com.wit.mad2bikeshop.firebase.FirebaseImageManager
import com.wit.mad2bikeshop.ui.auth.LoggedInViewModel
import com.wit.mad2bikeshop.ui.auth.Login
import com.wit.mad2bikeshop.utils.customTransformation
import timber.log.Timber

class Home : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
    private lateinit var homeBinding: HomeBinding
    private lateinit var navHeaderBinding: NavHeaderBinding
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var loggedInViewModel: LoggedInViewModel
    private lateinit var headerView : View

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        homeBinding = HomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(homeBinding.root)
        drawerLayout = homeBinding.drawerLayout
        val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        val navController = navHostFragment.navController

        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.

        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.bookFragment, R.id.bookingListFragment
            ), drawerLayout
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

        val navView = homeBinding.navView
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
        initNavHeader()
    }

    public override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        loggedInViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(LoggedInViewModel::class.java)
        loggedInViewModel.liveFirebaseUser.observe(this, Observer { firebaseUser ->
            if (firebaseUser != null)
                updateNavHeader(firebaseUser)
        })

        loggedInViewModel.loggedOut.observe(this, Observer { loggedout ->
            if (loggedout) {
                startActivity(Intent(this, Login::class.java))
            }
        })

    }

    private fun initNavHeader() {
        Timber.i("DX Init Nav Header")
        headerView = homeBinding.navView.getHeaderView(0)
        navHeaderBinding = NavHeaderBinding.bind(headerView)
    }

    private fun updateNavHeader(currentUser: FirebaseUser) {
        FirebaseImageManager.imageUri.observe(this, { result ->
            if(result == Uri.EMPTY) {
                Timber.i("DX NO Existing imageUri")
                if (currentUser.photoUrl != null) {
                    //if you're a google user
                    FirebaseImageManager.updateUserImage(
                        currentUser.uid,
                        currentUser.photoUrl,
                        navHeaderBinding.navHeaderImage,
                        false)
                }
                else
                {
                    Timber.i("DX Loading Existing Default imageUri")
                    FirebaseImageManager.updateDefaultImage(
                        currentUser.uid,
                        R.drawable.ic_book_nav_header,
                        navHeaderBinding.navHeaderImage)
                }
            }
            else // load existing image from firebase
            {
                Timber.i("DX Loading Existing imageUri")
                FirebaseImageManager.updateUserImage(
                    currentUser.uid,
                    FirebaseImageManager.imageUri.value,
                    navHeaderBinding.navHeaderImage, false)
            }
        })
        navHeaderBinding.navHeaderEmail.text = currentUser.email
        if(currentUser.displayName != null)
            navHeaderBinding.navHeaderName.text = currentUser.displayName
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }

    fun signOut(item: MenuItem) {
        loggedInViewModel.logOut()
        //Launch Login activity and clear the back stack to stop navigating back to the Home activity
        val intent = Intent(this, Login::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

My BookViewModel

```
package com.wit.mad2bikeshop.ui.book

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.wit.mad2bikeshop.firebase.FirebaseDBManager
import com.wit.mad2bikeshop.firebase.FirebaseImageManager
import com.wit.mad2bikeshop.model.BookManager
import com.wit.mad2bikeshop.model.BookModel

class BookViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val status = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

    val observableStatus: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = status

    fun addBook(firebaseUser: MutableLiveData<FirebaseUser>,
                booking: BookModel) {
        status.value = try {
            booking.profilepic = FirebaseImageManager.imageUri.value.toString()
            FirebaseDBManager.create(firebaseUser,booking)
            true
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
            false
        }
    }

//    fun updateBook(booking: BookModel){
//        status.value = try {
//        BookManager.update(booking)
//            true
//        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
//            false
//        }
//    }
}
```

My BookAdapter

```
package com.wit.mad2bikeshop.adapters

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.core.net.toUri
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.squareup.picasso.MemoryPolicy
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import com.wit.mad2bikeshop.R
import com.wit.mad2bikeshop.databinding.CardBookBinding
import com.wit.mad2bikeshop.model.BookModel
import com.wit.mad2bikeshop.utils.customTransformation

interface BookListener {
//    fun onDeleteBooking(booking: BookModel)
//    fun onUpdateBooking(booking: BookModel)
    fun onBookingClick(booking: BookModel)
}

class BookAdapter constructor(
    private var bookings: ArrayList<BookModel>,
    private val listener: BookListener,
    private val readOnly: Boolean)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<BookAdapter.MainHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MainHolder {
        val binding = CardBookBinding
            .inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)

        return MainHolder(binding, readOnly)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MainHolder, position: Int) {
        val booking = bookings[holder.adapterPosition]
        holder.bind(booking, listener)
    }

    fun removeAt(position: Int) {
        bookings.removeAt(position)
        notifyItemRemoved(position)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = bookings.size

    inner class MainHolder(val binding: CardBookBinding,private val readOnly : Boolean) :
                            RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        val readOnlyRow = readOnly

        fun bind(booking: BookModel, listener: BookListener) {
            binding.root.tag = booking
            binding.booking = booking
            binding.imageIcon.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            Picasso.get().load(booking.profilepic.toUri())
                .resize(200, 200)
                .transform(customTransformation())
                .centerCrop()
                .into(binding.imageIcon)
//
//            binding.name.text = booking.name
//            binding.phoneNumber.text = booking.phoneNumber
//            binding.date.text = booking.date
            binding.root.setOnClickListener { listener.onBookingClick(booking) }
//            binding.buttonDelete.setOnClickListener { listener.onDeleteBooking(booking) }
//            binding.buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener { listener.onUpdateBooking(booking) }

            binding.executePendingBindings()
            /* binding.imageIcon.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)*/
        }




    }
}
```

I believe the problem stems from the (FirebaseImageManager.imageUri.value.toString()) on my BookAdapter, as if I run a Timber.I statement it doesn't return anything at all. If I run Timber.i(FirebaseImageManager.imageUri.value.toString()+ "test"), it only returns test.

Here is a link to the full project https://github.com/foxxxxxxx7/MAD2bikeshop

Apologies if I wasn't clear enough, I am a novice.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I had to modify my rules on the firebase storage.